# Why is my .ttf file not converting properly to other formats using FontSquirrel or Transfonter?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've been tasked with creating a movie poster using HTML5 and CSS3. On Internet Explorer 10, the .ttf font works great, and the poster looks great. However, running the *index.html* file on Chrome or Safari does not properly render the font.

I asked my professor why this was the case, and he says not all OS's and browsers use the same font file type, and I need to generate multiple types for multiple browsers. He suggested I use FontSquirrel.

I attempted to upload my file, **Starjedi.ttf**, but I received a corrupt file error. I then attempted to use Transfonter, which successfully gave me a .zip package, but looking at the test page, the font doesn't render properly. Am I doing something wrong, or is my font not able to convert properly?

Here is my code that I use in my CSS file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "logo";
    src: url("../fonts/logo/Starjedi.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** With help from @Stephen_Thomas, I managed to get the conversion working. The conversion's `test.html` works fine in Chrome, but now my issue is implementing it into my code.

Here is the updated font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'star_jediregular';
    src: url('starjedi-webfont.eot');
    src: url('starjedi-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('starjedi-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('starjedi-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('starjedi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('starjedi-webfont.svg#star_jediregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

And here is when I set my font-family:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   Star Wars Title -------------------------------------------------- */
.logo {
    /* "Star" & "Wars" */
    font-family: 'star_jediregular'; /* TODO: Font doesn't work in Chrome */
    font-size: 180px;
    color: black;
    /* More code below, but irrelevant ... */
```

My font does not work in any browser, IE10, Chrome or Opera. Clearly I am embedding this font-face incorrectly, but I'm not sure where I went wrong?

**GOT IT WORKING** -- I was using incorrect file paths since the converted CSS code didn't account for my project directory structure (which makes total sense). Thanks!

Comment: I checked the font from [dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/star-jedi.font) and it converts fine. It does sound like you might have a bad file. Perhaps you can try downloading again.

Comment: Thanks @StephenThomas I re-downloaded the file and the conversion worked. I copied and pasted the given font-face in **stylesheet.css** and I changed my font family, but the font still does not render in Chrome. Am I doing something wrong?  **Edit**: I ran the test *font.html* file and the font properly renders in Chrome. I will mess around with my CSS file to see where I am going wrong. I will update this message when I can.

Comment: Gah! I'm such an idiot! The file path given by the converted format wasn't correct. I changed the file paths according to my project directory structure and it works on Chrome, Opera, and IE10! Thank you @stephen-thomas !